# Como executar um arquivo com PHP?

Tags: php

Eu queria saber algum código em PHP que faz me abrir um ficheiro `.exe`, ou seja uma linha que faça executar um arquivo `.exe` do mesmo servidor.

Comment: existe a função exec, mas dificilmente uma hospedagem compartilhada vai deixar isso habilitado em condições normais. Num servidor que você administre, dá para permitir, mas aí uma invasão via PHP compromete o servidor todo.

Comment: Bacco, eu quando me refiro a hospedagem é a servidor local(vertrigo) será que aí funcionará?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php

Comment: Não sei especificidades do seu caso. Teoricamente sim, mas precisa testar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conforme eu havia [comentado](/q/101626/#comment207415_101626) assim que a questão foi postada, você pode usar a função [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php):

```
exec( 'caminho/do/executavel', [array &$retorno], [ int &$status_erro ] );
```

Esta função funciona bem tanto em Linux quanto Windows, desde que usada com os caminhos corretos, obviamente.

Ela retorna apenas a última linha da saida. Num comando simples como 'pwd', esta função resolve sem precisar passar nada por referência. Se precisar de uma listagem de diretório, por exemplo, já tem que usar o parâmetro `&$retorno` ou por exemplo o `shell_exec()` descrito mais abaixo.

Se quiser aproveitar a saída do executável diretamente para a tela ou para download do lado do cliente, tem o [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.passthru.php) (lembre-se de setar os headers corretos na aplicação).

```
passthru( 'caminho/do/executavel', [ &$retorno ]);
```

A diferença desta última é que os dados vão direto para o cliente, sem você precisar dar `echo` ou qualquer função de saída.

Há também o [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php), para executar comandos como se os estivesse executando diretamente no *shell* do Linux, ou CMD do Windows:

```
system ( 'caminho/do/executavel', [ &$retorno ] );
```

Para não travar a aplicação enquanto o executável roda, redirecione a saída para algum *stream* ou arquivo (por exemplo, `caminho/do/executavel > /dev/null` no Linux ou `> NIL` no Windows)

Bem lembrado pelo @IvanFerrer, há um "parente" do `system()`, que é o [`shell_exec();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php), que tem uma diferença de sintaxe que pode ajudar em alguns casos - o retorno da função é o *output* do comando:

```
$listagem_do_diretório = shell_exec( 'ls -la' );
```

Não entrarei em detalhes, mas é bom comentar que ainda há o [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.popen.php) e o [`pcntl-exec()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pcntl-exec.php) para algumas necessidades mais especializadas. Mais detalhes podem ser vistos no manual.

**Notas:**

- É bom lembrar que geralmente os administradores de servidores de hospedagem desabilitam estas funções via PHP.ini, pois uma invasão via PHP comprometeria o resto do servidor todo.
- O `&` nos exemplos de sintaxe acima é apenas para indicar que os parâmetros são passados por referência. Você não deve digitar `&$retorno` no código real, apenas `$retorno`. Da mesma forma, os `[ ]` também são indicação de sintaxe, e não devem ser entendidos literalmente. Não ponha `[ ]` no código real.

Comment: Só para deixar um exemplo, se você quiser bloquear estas funções edite no php.ini o `disable_functions`, exemplo: `disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen`

Comment: É que eu não sei como funciona o teu servidor, mas supondo que o php+apache rode em um grupo de usuários especifico (sem root) então acho que pouco isto afetaria, claro que não sei se existe sploits dependendo da versão do sistema servidor, do apache e do php. Por via das duvidas bloqueia rs.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é que se você não restringe o open_basedir, mesmo que algum atacante não mexa na máquina, vai poder ver a estrutura do filesystem o suficiente pra dar uma noção da máquina, e achar outras brechas. O apache roda separado mesmo. Por padrão tem muita coisa no linux que outros users conseguem ler, mesmo não alterando, e restringir o PHP custa aproximadamente 2 minutos de trabalho :).

Answer (score 2):

Use a função PHP [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)!

```html
exec( 'caminho/do/executavel.exe', &$resultado);
echo $resultado;
```

**Observações**

1. `exec` deve estar habilitado

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Porque a página só para de carregar quando o executável está aberto? Como faço para evitar isso?

Comment: O método `exec()` também funciona para Linux, desde que esteja habilitado, mas o Linux tem o `shell_exec()` que faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: Eu desconhecia isso! Achava que o `shell_exec()` era pra um e o `exec()` para outro. Bem, vou editar então! O que o @Bacco falou então é verdade, mas sem apresentar solução fica difícil de considerar, né?! Obrigado, IvanFerrer!!!

Comment: Só uma dica não use o `&$resultado` isto esta descontinuado fora de funções, use o `&$variavel` apenas em funções ou métodos de classes, caso contrário irá emitir `warnings`.