# Processo "não bloqueante" em PHP

Tags: php, shell

uma ajuda.Tenho o seguinte código.

```
$output = shell_exec("php /sites/empresa/php/faturamento/gerar_fat_simulado.php ".$cliente.' '.$mes.' '.$ano.' '.$tipo);
```

Ele executa através do shell uma rotina bastante demorada que bloqueia todo o sistema até que ela seja concluída. Sei que o PHP não trabalha com Threads. Existe alguma forma de fazer com que isso não bloqueie o resto do sistema?
Obrigado.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101626/como-executar-um-arquivo-com-php/101795#101795

Comment: Esta resposta explica o problema quando se usa sessões e como evitar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57827/3635